# .load() send data using POST in the URL

Tags: jquery, url, post

I'm using jquery's .load() function to load some data inside a div of a page. The main page is `catalogue.php` and inside the div `#catalogue-content` I load the data from `load-products.php` using javascript when some filters are applied.

The point is that I send some id's within the url, and when I try to read it in `load-products.php` it fails because the URL is too long. I think that one solution could be using $_POST method instead of $_GET method, but I've tried it reading in older posts and I did'nt find the wright solution.

I would help some help, here's my code:

**JS**

```
var ids = '0001,0002,0003,000';
$("#catalogue-content").post('load-products.php?ids='+ids);
```

**load-products PHP**

```
$ids = $_GET['ids'];
```

Comment: are you missing the closing brackets for the post method?

Comment: The max querystring length in IE is 2,048 characters, Firefox is 65,536. Are you sure the querystring is too long?

Comment: No, I didn't miss id @SherinMathew

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the answer of the firebug is:

414 Request-URI Too Large

Comment: oh sorry to confuse you. But when i checked the questions first time, i couldn't see the closing brackets and semicolor for the post method. It is present now.

Comment: My bad, I missed it in the post, so I corrected it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:

```
var params = {
   ids : ids
 }    

$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url : 'load-products.php',
      data: params,
      success: function(data) {
        // replace content of #catalogue-content with returned data
        $("#catalogue-content").html(data);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Some error")
      }
})
```

And then in you load-products.php file use $_POST['ids']

Hope this helps and give you a start

Comment: The firebug reports me an error in:

var params = {
   ids = ids
}

Comment: "missing : after property id"

Comment: Apologise, I haven't testes this. It is fixed now in example code

Comment: params you can send some value

Comment: I'm afraid I don't find the way to make it work, but thank you anyway.

Comment: ManelMusti just pass the value  data: {id:id,other_info:other_info}
and receive with $_POST['id] and $_POST['other_info']

Comment: I've been able to recieve some data, now I have the start I needed to continue working, thanks a lot!

Comment: If you stuck post parts of your js and php file that are used for Ajax calls and we will figure it out!